# Eclipse JPA and MySQL - Generic vs Eclipse Link platform in JPA facet

Tags: mysql, eclipse, jakarta-ee, glassfish, eclipselink

When adding a JPA facet to an Eclipse project there is a choice between `Generic` and `Eclipse Link` platforms :

[image]

What are the pros cons of each one ?

I intend to set up the project with Glassfish and MySql

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GlassFish ships with EclipseLink as the default JPA provider. You will want to choose the EclipseLink platform so you get enhanced persistence.xml configuration (more graphical editing for example).

Think of it this way. Each JPA provider supports a version of the JPA specification (2.0 for example). Each JPA provider also supports proprietary extensions. If you want your code to be more portable, choose the Generic JPA provider. If you want to take advantage of features specific to a JPA provider, choose that JPA provider platform (like EclipseLink).

You can take a look at [this document](http://www.eclipse.org/webtools/dali/docs/dali_user_guide_2.3.pdf) which explains the difference between the two in a bit more detail. For example, section 4.2.5 explains the different options available in the persistence.xml editor options.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit ? Generic is what then ? A link with the differences or/and a comparison would be appreciated ;)